# Photo edit extensibility for UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

In Silverlight it was once possible to register an app for the edit-dialog in the photo hub (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202966(v=vs.105).aspx).

Is there an UWP-equivalent now? Or is there any other way, my app can be started from within the photos hub?

Comment: I think [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/A-Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10/11) is what you're after. Skip to **5:33**.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I am looking for a way, that users can start my app from within the built-in photos app, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not currently available in the Universal Platform. You can use the Windows Feedback tool ("Developer" section) or [UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/) to request that it be made available.

Comment: As suggested, I posted the idea to the UserVoice: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9831597-allow-launching-a-specific-app-for-a-photo-from-wi